# GAE python endpoints custom response headers

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, google-cloud-endpoints

I am currently using GAE with python and the endpoints.api_server
I can get headers from self.request state or os.environ but where can I add a custom header?
I'm trying to add a jwt to the header instead of passing it in the body to handle auth more easily.

Comment: I gave up on sending back custom headers. I read about intercepting with a servlet (for java) and if I use non-endpoints services, I can return the custom headers --
I changed some of the requests so that they would include the JWT when needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather late but the way I accomplished sending back custom response headers was by wrapping `send_wsgi_response` in endpoints.util. Here's an example:

```
import endpoints.util as util

# Note: If someone imports send_wsgi_response before here, the function 
# will NOT be decorated and the original function will be used until this bit runs
def add_headers(wsgi_func):  
    def wrapper(status, headers, content, start_response, cors_handler=None):
        headers.append(('Some-Header', 'some-value'))
        return wsgi_func(status, headers, content, start_response, cors_handler)
    return wrapper

util.send_wsgi_response = add_headers(util.send_wsgi_response)
```

Copied and pasted from [here](http://www.pygopar.com/how-to-add-custom-headers-to-google-cloud-endpoints)